# Is there a way to toggle the Shift Key on an iOS keyboard with Delphi XE5/iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

My problem is as follows...

I have a login screen requiring a username and password, which causes the Virtual Keyboard to be shown on entering the TEdit.

iOS7 has decided that turning on the Shift Key for the entry of of the first character is a good idea (it turns it off after the first character).

This makes sense when you are writing a sentence for example, but for a username (and especially for a password, where the character appears as a *), this is a bit of a nuisance.

Can anyone assist, so that when the edit field is entered and the keyboard pops up, the Shift Key is not on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `autocapitalizationType` option on a text field or text view, the default is "words" and you want" none.  Look for capitalization related properties on the text entry area control in Delphi, there should be something.

See the `UITextInputTraits` page for the full set of options, hopefully Delphi exposes this in some way.

https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Comment: Thanks Kendall.  A review of the documentation suggests that your answer is correct.  Unfortunately Delphi does not expose the property in a meaningful way, although there does seem to be an unimplemented placeholder for the setAutocorrectionType method of the TFMXVIewBase class.  So my next challenge will be to see if I can somehow extend the class to implement this by accessing the cocoa framework directly.  Thanks for your help.